# Add products per page pagination in WooCommerce?

Tags: plugins, wordpress, woocommerce

is there any way I can add a dropdown with number of product per page on the category page in WooCommerce. Like the dropdown contain the number 10,20,30 and when any option is selected that number of product load. Check the attached image fro reference.

[image: Product per page dropdown]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a plugin called [WooCommerce Products Per Page](https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-products-per-page/) that can do that.

- Once installed and activated go to the Settings -> Products Per Page
- The second option on that page is "List of dropdown options", by default it is set to "9 18 27 -1", change that to "10 20 30" and save the changes.
- There should be a dropdown list on the products page.